# d3 - append two objects to the same parent

Tags: d3.js

I don't have a "data" in my current project, I'm creating objects over time (with a timer).

Within the creation loop of every single object, I would like to append a div and a svg into the object.

This is how the object looks at it's creation:

```
<object></object>
```

..and this is how I want it to look after append:

```
<object><svg></svg><div></div></object>
```

When I chain-append both as usual, it does not work since it can only append the div into the svg. Therefore, I need a way to select the object.

When I try to select the object, it selects the first one only, therefore makes it impossible to append to the "current object in creation".

I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: where will the </svg> be?

Comment: just corrected @Incodeveritas

Comment: can you plunkr plz? but  i would probably create a selection, then append both the svg and div in separate instances.

Comment: Show your append code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you chain the .appends, so that you append to the svg instead of to the selection.

Store the selection in a temp variable, so you can do tmp.append("svg"...) and then tmp.append("div"...)